Google sheets if else statement issue
IF COLUMN B CONTAINS ANYTHING(STRING) FROM COLUMN AO THEN COLUMN M = '106', 
IF COLUMN B CONTAINS ANYTHING(STR) FROM COLUMN AP THEN COLUMN M = '105',
IF EMPTY LEAVE BLANK

How should I write the code for this issue?
AO and AP contains fixed data to use as reference.
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AO$1:AO, B1))), "106", IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AP$1:AP, B1))), "105", ""))

I've tried doing it like this but it disregards if its from AP or AO and will result in only showing 106 regardless if the reference data was found in AO or AP

You can try this direct comparison:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B12 <> "", IF((C1:C12 = "") * (D1:D12 = ""), " ", IF(B1:B12 = C1:C12, IF(B1:B12 = D1:D12, "both equal", "106"), IF(B1:B12 = D1:D12, "105", " "))), " "))

Suppose that my Column C is your Column AO, Column D is your Column AP and Column E is your Column M.
Sample data set:

Please adjust the column, and absolute values based on your requirements.
UPDATE: I have modified the formula, and considered most exceptions.
Reference:

ARRAYFORMULA

